# How to display data horizontally in SQL Server without using pivot and unpivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Is there any way to display Horizontal data in sql without using pivot and unpivot method ? Below image is a sample of using pivot and unpivot but I want to know is there any other method of doing it ?

## Example

### Original Data

```
+----+-------+-----------------+
| id | Place | Location        |
+----+-------+-----------------+
|  1 |  CP01 | 3.1415,101.7231 |
|  2 |  CP02 | 3.2314,101.3254 |
|  3 |  CP03 | 3.9415,101.0192 |
|  4 |  CP04 | 3.5490,102.0435 |
|  5 |  CP05 | 3.2562,101.2597 |
|  6 |  CP06 | 3.1134,102.5915 |
+----+-------+-----------------+
```

## Horizontal Data

```
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
| Cols     | 1               | 2               | 3               | ... |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
| Location | 3.1415,101.7231 | 3.2314,101.3254 | 3.9415,101.0192 | ... |
|    Place | CP01            | CP02            | CP03            | ... |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
```

[Image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We3Os.png)

Comment: Why do you not want to use `PIVOT`?

Comment: `PIVOT` won't produce rows like that. Is that exactly how you want your data to be? You'll have to union two PIVOTs together or get really extensive with your case/when, possibly generating arbitrary rows in a cross-join

Comment: ...or just do such presentational transformations properly, in the frontend, rather than trying to make a DBMS generate 2 'rows per row' or something...

Answer (score 0):

The similar way is you could use of cross apply with some conditional aggregation in order to achieve `pivot` and `unpivot` way

```
SELECT a.Col1, MAX(case when a.ID = 1 then a.Value end) [1],
               MAX(case when a.ID = 2 then a.Value end) [2],
               MAX(case when a.ID = 3 then a.Value end) [3]
FROM table T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Place', T.place, T.ID),
                    ('Location', T.Location, T.ID)
            ) as a(Col1, Value, ID)
group by a.Col1
```

Comment: I tried using this method, but the result is not what i wanted. The data need to be display Horizontal way

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @GeoData TABLE (Id INT, Place VARCHAR(10), [Location] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @GeoData

 SELECT 1,'CP01','3.1415,101.7231' 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'CP02','3.2314,101.3254'

SELECT  'Location' AS Cols,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 1 THEN t.Location END) AS [1],
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 2 THEN t.Location END) AS [2],
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 2 THEN t.Location END) AS [3]      
 FROM @GeoData t

 UNION ALL

 SELECT  'Place' AS Cols,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 1 THEN t.Place END) AS [1],
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 2 THEN t.Place END) AS [2],
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.Id = 2 THEN t.Place END) AS [3]     
 FROM @GeoData t
```